# Ordenar un arreglo con valores aleatorios sin usar sort

Tags: swift

Necesito ayuda para una tarea que consiste en ordenar un array con números aleatorios de forma descendente y ascendente mostrando los 3 arreglos (el original desordenado, el ascendente y el descendente) solo he podido generar el array original pero tengo problemas para el ordenamiento y me gustaría hacerlo de una forma fácil.

PD: estoy trabajando en un compilador online ya que no tengo mac :(

```
var lista_O: [Int] = []
var lista_Ma_Me: [Int] = []
var lista_Me_Ma: [Int] = []
var aux: Int = 0
var suma: Int = 0
var promedio: Int = 0
var z = 0

for i in 1...10 {
z = Int.random(in: 1...10)
suma = suma + z
lista_O.append(z)
}

for i in 0...10 {
for j  in 1...10 {
 if (lista_Ma_Me[i] < lista_Ma_Me[j]) {
  aux = lista_Ma_Me[i]
  lista_Ma_Me[i] = lista_Ma_Me[j]
  lista_Ma_Me[j] = aux
   }
  }
 }

 promedio = suma / 10

 print(lista_O)
 print("----Promedio----")
 print(promedio)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen métodos que se utilizaban antes para ordenar arrays como el método de la burbuja o quicksort. Los nuevos lenguajes suelen incluir un método de ordenación, como en el caso de Swift, por lo que esos métodos ya no son muy eficientes.

En el código que has puesto, has creado un array de 10 elementos, pero en el primer for de la ordenación, estas recorriendo 11 elementos, se te va a salir del rango. Ademas, estas ordenando lista_Ma_Me, que no has puesto ningún valor. Deberías rellenar los array con los mismos valores que rellenas lista_O.

El método de la burbuja básicamente dice que tienes que recorrer el array ordenando de cada vez el numero mayor o menor (depende de la condición del if) y si hay algún cambio volver a recorrer todo el array. Como veras es muy poco eficiente, pero te lo dejo así ya que es muy fácil de entender lo que hace.

```
func burbuja() {
var sw: Bool = true
while (sw) {
    sw = false
    for i in 0..<lista_O.count - 1 {
        if lista_O[i] > lista_O[i+1] {
            let swap = lista_O[i]
            lista_O[i] = lista_O[i+1]
            lista_O[i+1] = swap
            sw = true
        }
    }
}
```

}